# Having trouble getting webcam to work in android emulator, works fine on android phone

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am working on my capstone project with several other people. We have an app that is supposed to take a picture and apply image processing to the image using googles MLkit. It works fine on my friend's android phone but since I do not have one, I need to setup my webcam to test and finish my part of the project. I have spent hours trying to figure this out but have had no luck.

Here is the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.pg.teethdetection, PID: 3171
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pg.teethdetection/com.pg.teethdetection.DetectTeethActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x3 cmp=com.android.camera2/com.android.camera.CaptureActivity clip={text/uri-list U:content://com.pg.teethdetection.fileprovider/my_images/JPEG_20181022_150939_8076588917693759740.jpg} (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{56c9a53 3171:com.pg.teethdetection/u0a85} (pid=3171, uid=10085) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE flg=0x3 cmp=com.android.camera2/com.android.camera.CaptureActivity clip={text/uri-list U:content://com.pg.teethdetection.fileprovider/my_images/JPEG_20181022_150939_8076588917693759740.jpg} (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{56c9a53 3171:com.pg.teethdetection/u0a85} (pid=3171, uid=10085) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA
    at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1942)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1910)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1860)
    at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityManager.java:3755)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1669)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4586)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:767)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4544)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:754)
    at com.pg.teethdetection.DetectTeethActivity.dispatchTakePictureIntent(DetectTeethActivity.java:160)
    at com.pg.teethdetection.DetectTeethActivity.onCreate(DetectTeethActivity.java:134)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
 Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.checkStartAnyActivityPermission(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:1788)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:717)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivity(ActivityStarter.java:544)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStarter.java:1099)
    at com.android.server.am.ActivityStarter.execute(ActivityStarter.java:486)
```

I have tried using different system images for the emulator, setting webcam0 to just front, just back, to both.

Request permission code:

```
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA: {
            for (int i = 0, len = permissions.length; i < len; i++) {
                String permission = permissions[i];

                if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                    boolean
                            showRationale =
                            ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                                    this, permission);

                    if (showRationale) {
                        showAlert();
                    } else if (!showRationale) {
                        // user denied flagging NEVER ASK AGAIN
                        // you can either enable some fall back,
                        // disable features of your app
                        // or open another dialog explaining
                        // again the permission and directing to
                        // the app setting
                        saveToPreferences(DetectTeethActivity.this, ALLOW_KEY, true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // other 'case' lines to check for other
        // permissions this app might request
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the stacktrace. It says you haven't granted the CAMERA permission.

Comment: A permission pop up appears on the emulator when I open the app but the error occurs before I am even able to accept it.

Comment: It sounds like you aren't waiting for the permission to be granted before continuing. Permission requests are done asynchronously. You need to carry out logic dependent on that permission only if it's granted (if it's not granted, do it in `onPermissionResult()` if the user did grant the permission).

Comment: I just edited the question to add our code for onRequestPermissionResult(). I feel like I shouldn't have to change much here because it works perfectly on his phone. I could be wrong though.

Comment: Is this person's phone on Lollipop?

Comment: You also don't actually have any camera-depending logic in the case that the permission is granted, which means you're probably calling camera-dependent code immediately after requesting permission, which won't work.

Comment: Okay, ill look into that thanks! Also I dont know what lolipop is. Its just his android phone.

Comment: Lollipop is the Android version. Android 5.

Comment: I changed the permissions code from the second screen to the start screen. It works on my laptop but does not work on my desktop. There error went away when I click the 'Start Capture' button however it still says it cannot access the camera. Any idea what this may be caused by?